# Finding local extrema AND assuring alternating minima/maxima

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I'm trying to implement some algorithms in Python from different papers and some require a peak/through detection where local minima and maxima are alternating. That should always be the case of course in an analog signal.

However when working with discrete Signals this is not always the case as you can see with this simple example:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmax,argrelmin,argrelextrema
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure("local extrema")
ax = fig.subplots()
x = range(0,10)
y = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0])
local_minima, = list(argrelmin(np.array(y)))
local_maxima, = list(argrelmax(np.array(y)))
ax.plot(local_maxima, y[local_maxima],"x",color="orange")
ax.plot(local_minima, y[local_minima],"x",color="orange")
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: simple min/max detection]

I know that I can adjust the argrelmax and argrelmin functions but no matter what I do, its always somehow flawed.

Here only two maxima are found. So there are no alternating extrema.

Is there a way to automatically detect extremas and assure they are alternating, or do I have to implement some kind of workaround? (Ideas for that are welcome too)

Comment: What do you want the expected output to be? I am confused

Comment: Hi. While reading about argrelmin I stumbled across this note: 'This function uses argrelextrema with np.less as comparator. Therefore, it requires a strict inequality on both sides of a value to consider it a minimum. This means flat minima (more than one sample wide) are not detected. In case of 1-D data find_peaks can be used to detect all local minima, including flat ones, by calling it with negated data.' So it looks like you should use find_peaks for your application. Alternatively you can use `argrelextrema` and change the comparator to `np.less_equal` or `np.greater_equal`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant with 
"I know that I can adjust the argrelmax and argrelmin "

Comment: But even with np.less_equal a minimum would not be found because either side of the "flat minima" doesn't fullfill the condition

Comment: And when you increase the width to lets say n=5 or even wider you run the risk of missing local extrema

Comment: @TomMcLean I expect a minimum to be detected at one of the two points between peaks

Comment: You can also search for places where differential is equal 0 (`np.diff`) and change values there, e.g. adding small triangle signal.

Comment: Yeah I will keep that in mind, if my posted solution leads to further problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I previously disregarded unfortunately. The Problem with argrelmax,argrelmin and argrelextrema was that they had difficulties detecting flat peaks/throughs because sometimes they found two maxima using np.greater_equal as comparator (beginning and end of flat peak), which lead to non alternating maxima/minima.

After Flows answer I revisited find_peaks from scipy.signal, which I previously disregarded, because in the first few sentences it said: "finds all local maxima by simple comparison of neighboring values" so I thought it had the same flaws as the others.

But in reality it detects flat peaks with only one index at the middle (rounded down) of the peak, no matter how wide apparently.

Thus this solved my Problem for this simple case:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmax,argrelmin, argrelextrema, find_peaks
fig = plt.figure("local extrema")
ax = fig.subplots()
x = range(0,10)
y = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0])
peaks,_ = find_peaks(y)
throughs,_ = find_peaks(np.negative(y))

local_maxima = list(peaks)
local_minima = list(throughs)


ax.plot(x,y)
ax.plot(local_maxima, y[local_maxima],"x",color="orange")
ax.plot(local_minima, y[local_minima],"x",color="orange")

plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see now the minima is detected.

I will have to see if it works on my real world data though, but I think it should. Thx!